# Trying to polyfill JSDOM request

Tags: javascript, polyfills, jsdom

Im trying to fetch the html content of a [page](https://rarible.com/collection/0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6?filter%5Bfilter%5D%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=OPEN_FOR_OFFERS&filter%5Bfilter%5D%5BhasRewards%5D=false) by using the [JSDOM object](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) combined with the [polyfill package](https://github.com/bigslycat/mq-polyfill).

I have this code:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import matchMediaPolyfill from 'mq-polyfill';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';


export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse) {
  //Parameters
  const { collection } = req.query;
  if (collection?.length != 42) {
    res.status(200).json("Collection length needs to be 42!");
  } else {
    JSDOM.fromURL("https://rarible.com/collection/" + collection, {
      runScripts: "dangerously",
      pretendToBeVisual: true,
      resources: "usable"
    }).then(dom => {
      const {window} = new JSDOM(dom);
      matchMediaPolyfill(window);
      window.matchMedia('(min-width: 920px)');
      //var rendered = dom.window;
      res.status(200).json([{ window }]);
    });
    
  }
}
```

Im getting this error at the moment:

```
error - unhandledRejection: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Comment: `window` is circular because `window.window` points to `window`, and `window.window.window` points to `window.window` which points to `window`, and so on. I think you get it. Why are you sending the entire window object, though?